# Sum of Chi-squared Variables

Tags: distributions, convolution, chi-squared-distribution, sums-of-squares

What is the distribution of the variable $Y$ which is given by
$$Y = \sum^N_{i=1} Z_i X_i $$ 
where :

$Z_1,\dotsc,Z_N$ are independent and identically distributed and the density function $f_Z(z)$ is known (a shifted chi-square distribution),

$X_i \sim\chi^2_L(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the noncentrality paramter and $X_1,\dotsc,X_N$ are i.i.d. as well.

The question is:

(a) what is the distribution of $Y$ when $\lambda=0$.

(b) what is the distribution of $Y$ when $\lambda\ne 0$.

Comment: You are asking "What is the distribution of the variable $Y$..." but then saying "..and the density function $f_Y(y)$... is known (a shifted chi-square distribution)" so you know the density function of $Y$ already.  What is the question that you really meant to ask?

Comment: Did you mean the $Z$'s have a shifted $\chi^2$ distribution? Also, in the case of a $\chi^2$ distribution (or any continuous distribution actually) the density function is not equivalent to ${\rm Prob}(Y = y)$. In fact, for a continuous random variable ${\rm Prob}(Y = y) = 0$ for all $y$.

Comment: just fixed, the density $f(z)$ is known.

Comment: Are the $X_{i}$'s independent of each other?

Comment: yes, the $X_i$ are independent as well...

Comment: Corsario, that is the correct answer (although it won't be pretty to implement). I suggest posting it as an answer. Note you've also assumed that each $X_i$ is independent of each each $Z_j$ for $i \neq j$ (for the convolution part), but I'd imagine that was intended as part of Remy's description.

Comment: isn't there a closed form for the sum of scaled or weighted chi square variables?

Comment: Perhaps Remy, but in this case the weights are random variables, so it's not that simple. I think the answer lies in Corsario's comment.

Comment: what happens if the weights are not random variables, but each weight is differnet? are there any closed forms for that?

Comment: Wow, What happened to Corsario's comment?